# How to read secure from network stream?

Tags: c#

Currently I am working on a little project which works over the network. I have written a network manager which reads and writes to a stream. But I have problems when I try to join my reading thread. When I call the thread.join method the thread starts hanging. Here my code:

```
private TcpClient playerClient;
private NetworkStream playerStream;
private Thread readThread;
private bool isReading;

public void Read()
{
    while (this.isReading == true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.playerStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                continue;
            }

            List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            int currentByte = 0;

            while (this.playerStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                currentByte = this.playerStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
                receivedBytes.Add(buffer[0]);
            }

            this.FireOnDataReceived(receivedBytes.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        {
            this.FireOnConnectionLost();
        }
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    try
    {
        this.isReading = false;
        this.playerStream.Close();
        this.playerClient.Close();
        this.readThread.Join();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        this.playerStream = this.playerClient.GetStream();
        this.readThread = new Thread(this.Read);
        this.isReading = true;
        readThread.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
        this.FireOnConnectionLost();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the empty catch block? Remove the try/catch entirely so you can catch exceptions should they occur.

Comment: Why would you want to join read thread?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want to join the read thread when the server stops or the player disconnect

Comment: Why? I don't see any reason for that. Did you read [what it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: @Thomas5897 the point Camilo is trying to make is why use a seperate thread if you are just going to stop the first thread while the 2nd runs.

Comment: What does your call-stack say?  Where is it hanging?  Add some trace messages, what code path is it executing when it is hanging?  Or is it inside a blocking call?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh yeah the thread.join is useless here. I missed that xd